# DirectAdmin 2 users same folder

Tags: linux

So I'm still a rookie in devops but I am looking for a way where we can link a folder from user1 to a folder from user2.

I guess its sort of a symbolic link? 
How would you do something like that? Or what is the best solution to do this? Ca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create hardlinks to directories. 
So, Yes, you can create symbolic links `ln -s <Target> <Link>` however, please keep in mind the access permissions.